# Why do i get an an error on paint method when the parameters are correct?

Tags: java, oop

I am facing an issue with the paint method in the below program. The error "void Stage.paint(Graphic g, Point mouseloc)" and the error "paint cannot be resolved to a type". I have inputted the correct parameters and have set the fields and constructors properly. The error are in italics.Sorry i am new to coding and hopefully you can help me

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


class Main extends JFrame {

class App extends JPanel {
    
    Stage stage;

    public App() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 720));
        stage = new Stage();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        *stage.paint(g, getMousePosition());*
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main window = new Main();
    window.run();
}

private Main() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    App canvas = new App();
    this.setContentPane(canvas);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        this.repaint();  
    }
}
}


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Stage {

Grid grid;
Terrain sand;
Terrain oasis;
Terrain palm_tree;
Terrain wall;
Random RandomNo = new Random();
int number;

public Stage() {
    grid = new Grid();
for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        number = 1 + RandomNo.nextInt(10);
        if (number <= 4) {
            sand = new Sand(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
        } else if (number == 1) {
            oasis = new Oasis(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
        } else if (number == 2) {
            wall = new Wall(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
        } else if (number == 3) {
            palm_tree = new PalmTree(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
        }

    }
}

*public paint(Graphics g, Point mouseLoc){*
    grid.paint(g, mouseLoc);
    sand.paint(g);
    oasis.paint(g);
    wall.paint(g);
    palm_tree.paint(g);

}
}
}

import java.awt.*;

class Grid {
//fields
Cell[][] cells = new Cell[20][20];

// constructor
public Grid(){
    for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++){
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(10+35*i,10+35*j);
        }
    }
}

// methods
public void paint(Graphics g, Point mousePos){
    for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++){
            cells[i][j].paint(g, mousePos);
        }
    }
}
public Cell cellAtColRow(int c, int r){
    return cells[c][r];
}
}


import java.awt.*;


class Cell extends Rectangle {
// fields

static int size = 35;

//constructors
public Cell(int x, int y){
    super(x,y,size,size);

}

//methods

void paint(Graphics g, Point mousePos){      
    
    if(contains(mousePos)){
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    } 
     else {
       
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    
    }
    g.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x,y,size,size);
}

public boolean contains(Point p){
    if (p != null){
        return super.contains(p);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `public paint(Graphics g, Point mouseLoc){` <- Isn't a valid decleration

Comment: How do i declare it as a type or import

Comment: Please fix the question so that we can see clearly what classes are defined in what files.  (And fix the indentation!)  I cannot tell what classes are nested and what classes are top level.  And I cannot tell if there are actually `package` declarations there that you have left out.

Comment: Thank you guys sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: It is not necessarily stupid.  But you have shown us a "wall of code" that is incorrectly formatted and ... ambiguous ... because we can't see what is in what file.  That makes it difficult to figure out exactly what is causing the error.  It also doesn't help that the error message you reported says `Stage.paint` but the code (apparently) says `stage.paint`.  They are very different things.

Comment: And (apparently) there are other compilation errors that you haven't mentioned ... that may be the cause of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems...

First `public paint(Graphics g, Point mouseLoc){` is not a valid declaration, you're missing the return type.

It should be `public void paint(Graphics g, Point mouseLoc) {`

Second, you have a misplaced `}`, which means that `paint` is actually been declared inside the constructor...

```
public Stage() {
    grid = new Grid();
    for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            number = 1 + RandomNo.nextInt(10);
            if (number <= 4) {
                sand = new Sand(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            } else if (number == 1) {
                oasis = new Oasis(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            } else if (number == 2) {
                wall = new Wall(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            } else if (number == 3) {
                palm_tree = new PalmTree(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            }

        }
    }

    public paint(Graphics g, Point mouseLoc){
        grid.paint(g, mouseLoc);
        sand.paint(g);
        oasis.paint(g);
        wall.paint(g);
        palm_tree.paint(g);

    }
}
```

It should be more like...

```
public Stage() {
    grid = new Grid();
    for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            number = 1 + RandomNo.nextInt(10);
            if (number <= 4) {
                sand = new Sand(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            } else if (number == 1) {
                oasis = new Oasis(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            } else if (number == 2) {
                wall = new Wall(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            } else if (number == 3) {
                palm_tree = new PalmTree(grid.cellAtColRow(i, j));
            }

        }
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g, Point mouseLoc){
    grid.paint(g, mouseLoc);
    sand.paint(g);
    oasis.paint(g);
    wall.paint(g);
    palm_tree.paint(g);

}
```